# How to resolve the error "npm run build" exited with 1 vercel in vercel while deploy nextjs app?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I am getting this error while trying to deploy my nextjs app. I have tried these solutions but not works for me.

"Build & Development Settings", override the Build command and write CI='' npm run build not works.

CI=false not works

```
[00:40:43.944] Cloning github.com/AnoshaJaved123/landing (Branch: main, Commit: ea731c3)
[00:40:44.258] Previous build cache not available
[00:40:44.831] Cloning completed: 887.407ms
[00:40:45.272] Running "vercel build"
[00:40:45.821] Vercel CLI 28.10.3
[00:40:46.180] Installing dependencies...
[00:40:52.830] npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
[00:41:02.288] 
[00:41:02.288] added 549 packages in 16s
[00:41:02.289] 
[00:41:02.289] 109 packages are looking for funding
[00:41:02.289]   run `npm fund` for details
[00:41:02.310] Detected Next.js version: 13.0.4
[00:41:02.315] Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
[00:41:02.316] Running "npm run build"
[00:41:02.652] 
[00:41:02.653] > web-builder@0.1.0 build
[00:41:02.653] > next build
[00:41:02.653] 
[00:41:02.979] info  - Loaded env from /vercel/path0/.env
[00:41:03.127] Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
[00:41:03.128] This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
[00:41:03.128] You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
[00:41:03.128] https://nextjs.org/telemetry
[00:41:03.128] 
[00:41:03.260] info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
[00:41:06.141] info  - Creating an optimized production build...
[00:41:32.575] info  - Compiled successfully
[00:41:32.575] info  - Collecting page data...
[00:41:38.362] 
[00:41:38.363] > Build optimization failed: found pages without a React Component as default export in 
[00:41:38.363] pages/Editor/grapesUtils
[00:41:38.363] pages/templates/grapesUtils
[00:41:38.363] 
[00:41:38.363] See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/page-without-valid-component for more info.
[00:41:38.364] 
[00:41:38.417] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Comment: found pages without a React Component as default export in 
`pages/Editor/grapesUtils`
and `pages/templates/grapesUtils`, but all pages must have default export

Comment: Check your pages in pages/Editor/grapesUtils and pages/templates/grapesUtils, make sure you export default your page component functions